# Must the classes in Django's many-to-many relationship be in the same models.py file?

Tags: django, many-to-many

Please help me better understand how the `ManytoManyField` works in Django. Maybe the examples I've seen are simple ones for beginners, but it seems in all the examples, the classes involved in `ManytoManyFields` are in the same `models.py` file. In my exercise (following a [tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/django-forms-for-many-to-many-fields-d977dec4b024), I put the two classes in two different `models.py` file(different apps), and am struggling to make them connect. So my question #1: Do the classes in Django's many-to-many relationship have to be in the same `models.py` file? #2 For a true many-to-many relationship, do I need to create a "through" table/relationship?

Here is the relevant code snippets from the tutorial:

```
#app='household'
class Member(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # household = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='uploads/members/', default='/icons/member.svg')    
        
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s Household | %s' % (self.user, self.name)

#app=meals
class Meal(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    date = models.DateField()    
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Member')
```

Comment: No, these can be from a different app.

Comment: What do you mean with a "true" many-to-many relation.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem What I tried to say was: I didn't want a round-about fix (as some clever programmers can do). I wanted to figure out how the manytomanyfield works. One of the tutorials mentioned a "through table" as the way to connect the different ends of the relationship. But it's not clear to me where the through table fits in.

Comment: if you do not specify a `through=...` model, Django will create a "hidden" one, and thus create a corresponding table for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #1: Do the classes in Django's many-to-many relationship have to be in the same models.py file?

**No**. If for example the other model is `Foo` in `app2`, you can write this as:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    foos = models.ManyToManyField('app2.Foo')
```

> #2 For a true many-to-many relationship, do I need to create a "through" table/relationship?

**No**. Django will create a hidden model for the `ManyToManyField` if you do not specify a `through=…` yourself. That model will have two `ForeignKey`s: one to the "source" model, and one to the "target" model.

If you want to add extra data in the many-to-many relation, you defines a custom `through=…` model to add extra data besided the two `ForeignKey`s.

Comment: That worked! (Well, the migrations worked.) I knew the two classes weren't connecting, but couldn't figure out why and tweaking the models.py files made things worse. But following your example and changing "members = models.ManyToManyField('Member')" to "members = models.ManyToManyField('household.Member')" solved that problem. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized my mistake: If the two classes are in the same 'models.py' file, then no need for 'app2' in 'app2.Foo'. Simply importing the class from app2 isn't enough.

Comment: @YCode: if the two are in the same app, you can omit the name of the app, if these are different, you prefix it with the name of the app.

Comment: Understood. If only Django Docs made that point explicitly :-)